# Static global variables in Go

Tags: go

I am new in Go language and I need some help. I have declared a global variable but the problem is that it does not keep its value. It would be solved with a static variable but no such variables exist in Go. How should I solve this?

`gID` is a global variable. This function is called twice. On the first call `if` code is executed. On the second, `else` code is executed. I want the second struct `Learner` instance, to get first Learner's instance ID.

**I have to mention that NewLearner is called twice from two different files from different packages**.

```
func NewLearner(name string, peerURLs types.URLs, clusterName string, now *time.Time) *Learner {

    l := &Learner{
        RaftAttributes: RaftAttributes{PeerURLs: peerURLs.StringSlice()},
        Attributes:     Attributes{Name: name},
    }

    var b []byte
    sort.Strings(l.PeerURLs)
    for _, p := range l.PeerURLs {
        b = append(b, []byte(p)...)
    }

    b = append(b, []byte(clusterName)...)
    if now != nil {
        b = append(b, []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d", now.Unix()))...)
        hash := sha1.Sum(b)
        l.ID = types.ID(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(hash[:8]))
        gID=l.ID
        return l
    }  else {
        l.ID = gID
        return l    
    }

}
```

Comment: A code sample along with expected vs actual behavior could really help us help you.

Comment: It only changes when you change it. If you want a constant, [use a constant](https://tour.golang.org/basics/15).

Comment: I don't need a constant. What I need is something equal to static.

Comment: You can use package-level variables that are similar to global static variables. "static" doesn't really exist in Go since it does not have classes.

Comment: can you add the declaration of gID

Comment: The calls to `NewLearner` would also be useful. Or even a runnable example at http://play.golang.org

Comment: @the4thamigo_uk , gID is declared on the top of the file as var gID types.ID .

Comment: Are you sure `gID` is being set in the if block? maybe try to output it after it has been set with `fmt.Printf("gID=%v", gID)`. where is `types.ID` defined?

Comment: @robbrit: You can do silly things with function closures to create a function-local variable much like a C static function variable. Set a variable equal to the result of a function that closes over a variable and returns a function.

Comment: @the4thamigo_uk I printed gID and it does take the value of l.ID. Problem is on else statement. I expect to print a hash and it gives me 0.

Comment: Please edit your questions with more information. We need to know 1. How gID was declared, 2. How are u attempting to call `NewLearner`.

Comment: Many important details are missing, but I suspect another part of the code is inadvertently changing gID, or that the order of its initialization is not well-defined. I try to avoid problems like this by reducing the scope of such vars by defining them in a struct that also defines the rest of the interface such as NewLearner(). The var can be initialized in the struct constructor, e.g., NewMyStruct(), and clients can initialize and use their own instance of the struct with a clear program flow.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a channel? You can have channel (global in your context) of `uint64`.

```
idChan := make(chan uint64)
```

And then inside your if condition you can put the `gID` in the `idChan` and read the same from your `else` condition.. something like this:

```
    if now != nil {
        b = append(b, []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d", now.Unix()))...)
        hash := sha1.Sum(b)
        l.ID = types.ID(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(hash[:8]))
        idChan <- l.ID
        return l
    }  else {
        l.ID <- idChan
        return l    
    }
```

Do remember to close your channel appropriately though if you dont want to use it anywhere else anymore.

Although, i must advise that such stuffs are usually better and more safely handled by goroutines with waitgroups probably since you actually want to share a value. In your case something like maybe a goroutine that does if part and another that does the else part and then share this channel amongst those two goroutines and wait on the wait groups for code that depends on these goroutines completion. That really is what concurrency is.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that the package variable doesn't keep its value might be caused by concurrency.
I would solve your problem that way. Use a package variable with a mutex around in case the function is called concurrently.

```
import "sync"

var(
    gID  uint64
    muID sync.Mutex
)

func myfunc(param bool) {
    var id uint64
    if param {
        id = newID()

        muID.Lock()
        gID = id
        muID.Unlock()
    } else {
        muID.Lock()
        id = gID
        muID.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and my program keeps having the problem that I have told. Maybe it is not a concurrency matter.

Comment: Does your now var changes between each call?
Is your computation of hash correct? (don't have time to try it right now)